# How to add a module in an LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to create a new module filled with some global functions can be called in other module.
But when linking, `clang` shows:

> "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64".

Here is the function code:

```
LLVMContext context;
Module* module = new llvm::Module("testModule",context);
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(context);
std::string funcName = "funcAdd";
std::string bbName = "entry";
Function* func = llvm::Function::Create(type, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, funcName, module);
llvm::BasicBlock *entry = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(context, funcName, func);
builder.SetInsertPoint(entry);
Function::arg_iterator args = func->arg_begin();
llvm::Value *op0 = args++;
llvm::Value *op1 = args++;
llvm::Value *retValue = builder.CreateAdd(op0, op1);
builder.CreateRet(retValue);
```

I call it in a `FunctionPass` when the IR instruction is `add`:

```
Type* op0ty = inst->getOperand(0)->getType();
Type* op1ty = inst->getOperand(1)->getType();
llvm::FunctionType *funcTy = llvm::FunctionType::get(ty, {op0ty,op1ty}, false);
Module *instModule = instruction->getModule();
Function *callfunc = dyn_cast<Function>(instModule->getOrInsertFunction("funcAdd", funcTy));
callfunc->setCallingConv(CallingConv::C);
llvm::Value *op0 = inst->getOperand(0);
llvm::Value *op1 = inst->getOperand(1);
CallInst *CI = instBuilder.CreateCall(callfunc, {op0,op1});
inst->replaceAllUsesWith(CI);
inst->eraseFromParent();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the bitcode module created by the first code fragment added during linking along with whatever bitcode is emitted by the pass?

Comment: I don't know where the new module added..

Comment: well, that surely doesn't help. How many things do you compile? One is the pass and the other is the program that emits the new module? Or are they both placed in the same pass?

Comment: I need to add a new module when compiling.